# How to preload angular2 views so will not flicker white page on first load?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I am building an angular 2 app in plain JS.
My problem is that when I change from a page to another it flicker a white page until the new view is rendered. This happens for all components only first time I access them. If I go to same route second time the page is loaded without white page.
I capture the screen to explain better my problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5pOsXT-4rdTbmtuVnlUdXRMdE0/view?usp=sharing

Here is my main view:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<nav id="menu">
    <a [routerLink]="['Page1']">Page 1</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['Page2']">Page 2</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['Page3']">Page 3</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['Page4']">Page 4</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['Page5']">Page 5</a>
</nav>
```

RouteConfig is defined like this:

```
AppComponent = ng.router
    .RouteConfig([
        {path: '/page1', name:"Page1", component: Page1Component, useAsDefault: true },
        {path: '/page2', name:"Page2", component: Page2Component},
        ...
    ])
    (AppComponent);
```

And all my components have a .html file and a .css file like this:

```
Page1Component = ng.core
    .Component({
        selector: 'rl-page1',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/page1/view.html',
        styleUrls: ['app/components/page1/style.css'],
        directives: [ng.router.ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: [ng.router.Router, function(router) {
            this.router = router;


        }]
    });
```

From what it looks like angular cache pages after I access them and at second access will display instantly (without white flickering). I search how I can preloade this but I can't find any answer or method on this.

Please let me know if you need more code.

(I don't use Page1, Page2 in real app, only for this question I changed to be more clear for example)

Thanks.

**EDIT: 2016-03-18**

I try to use DynamicComponentLoader to load all the components in a hidden div. The code looks like this in AppComponent:

```
ngOnInit: function(){
    this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(Page1Component, this.elementRef, 'preloadpages');
    this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(Page2Component, this.elementRef, 'preloadpages');
},
```

and the html where is loaded is: `<div style="display: none;"><div #preloadpages></div></div>`

But I faced 2 problems:

1. If one of my component has in the constructor RouteParams like this:

   constructor: [ng.router.RouteParams, function(routeParam) {
       ...
   }],
   I am getting this error: `EXCEPTION: No provider for RouteParams! (class19 -> RouteParams)`
2. All components are loaded just like you open it. If I have a ajax call in a constructor that ajax call is created and all the components html will be appended in my hidden div. Here can be a performance problem if at start I try to load like 5 components and some make ajax calls. I am looking if there is a solution to load only html + css or to send a flag to component constructor to know that I am loading hidden just for preaching.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Paraphrasing https://stackoverflow.com/a/37298914/441662

The problem is that the files are loaded separately, which you can prevent using something like webpack that compiles the sources into bundles which can include both your app and the templates used in the routes. (altough I still can't explain the jump to the top of the page).

Here's how you can modify the webpack config of the [angular/angular2-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed) project:

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...,
  "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
},
```

webpack.config.js

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    ...,
    { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html' }
  ]
}
```

Example usage in your-component.ts

```
@Component({
  template: require('app/components/your-component/your-component.html')
})
```

Now the routes are loaded instantly and there is no flickering or jumping going on.

Answer (score 1):

Add a wrapper around the `<router-outlet>`

```
<div [hidden]="!isInitialized">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

In the page component set `isInitialized` to `false`. Then call

```
this.router.navigate(['Page1'])
.then(_ => this.router.navigate(['page2']))
.then(_ => this.router.navigate(['page3']))
...
.then(_ => {
    this.isInitialized = true; 
    this.router.navigate(['Page1']);
});
```

Comment: Hi. I finaly mange to make a working version of this. If I only try to load 1 page is working ok. If I try to load more than 1 I get an error. Here is html: `<div style="display: none;"><div #preloadpages></div></div>`     and to load a component I call `this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(Page1Component, this.elementRef, 'preloadpages');` and `this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(Page2Component, this.elementRef, 'preloadpages');` for second component.    And the error I get is: `EXCEPTION: No provider for RouteParams! (class19 -> RouteParams)` Something very generic.

Comment: Do you have `RouteParams` as parameter in one of the components?

Comment: Yes. I have in the constructor something like this: `constructor: [ng.router.Router, ... function(router,...) { ... }`

Comment: Actually on 2nd thought. I don't think my answer is a good approach.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the update. In this new way I see that I have to navigate all pages at beginning. I have soma pages that are accessible only from page3 for example (lets name it page3-1). So I was thinking to preload page3-1 (available only from page3) only when user go to page3. So I don't load at beginning pages that user can't access in one click from home.

Comment: Hard for me to know what would make sense in your scenario. I just tried to explain the basic idea behind it. Just navigate to the pages you actually want to get preloaded. I also just saw that I had a mistake, sorry. This can't work with `*ngIf`. Use `[hidden]=".."` instead (fixed in my answer already)

Comment: Thanks for help. I will make some testes and see what is faster and consume less memory.

Comment: This approach didn't work for me, but I came up with a new one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286283/is-there-a-way-to-preload-routes-in-angular-2-to-prevent-white-flickering-and-ju/37286284#37286284).